# Charging at over 5W through a USB-A-to-USB-C cable

Tags: usb, usb-c, usb-pd

I'm trying to use [this](https://www.scosche.com/ipad-usb-car-charger-two-port-1) charger to charge a USB-C device (a MacBook).

The charger is specified for 12W (5V, 2.4A), and has Type-A, non-superspeed connectors. The MacBook states up to 20V, 1.5A or up to 20.3V, 3A.

When connected, the MacBook recognizes the power source, but states that it isn't charging. In reality, it charges at a rate consistent with a 5V, 1A source.

I understand that most 5V, >1A solutions were proprietary solutions, but is there any way to build (or ideally, buy) a cable that'd allow to charge at a faster rate?

Note: I've seen [USB Power Delivery over Type-A connector](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/544003) and while it might lead to the answer, I haven't found it yet.

---

2021-07-13 edit:

I just tested the same MacBook & cable with an old Apple 10W USB-A charger (A1357). The MacBook sees it as an 8W source, and an USB current monitor sees 1.4A.

So the issue is not the cable, or at least not only the cable.

Comment: This is more complex than it seems, because at the very least if you want the mac to draw >1.5A at 5V then you need the cable to say that it supports 3A, something you are not going to find in an A-C cable. Your almost certainly going to have to spend more than a 12v USB-c adapter would cost, if its possible at all.

Comment: Interesting. This somewhat implies that it requires an active cable, which surprises me. If you have any recommended reading on that topic (besides the 547-pages USB-PD specification), please let me know. And agreed on the last part - this is likely more academic than practical.

Comment: For 5A its an actual chip: https://satechi.net/blogs/news/identifying-usb-c-e-mark-cables. I believe it communicates on the CC bus. for 3A vs 1.5A it uses a pull-up resistor on the CC line: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/446528/why-would-a-usb-c-adapter-have-a-pull-up-resistor